# How to change key array php

Tags: php

How to change key **array php** from

```
   array(
          [0]=>Joni
          [1]=>Jono
          [2]=>Riki
          [3]=>Budi
    );
```

**Change index to:**

```
array(
      [nominal]=>Joni
      [nominal]=>Jono
      [nominal]=>Riki
      [nominal]=>Budi
   );
```

Comment: Simply write a foreach loop and make it as per requirement..

Comment: since the key in an array is an index, which means it should be unique in array, So you can't have same key for all the values in an array

Comment: where did you get the nominal from? array with same size? or fix value?

Comment: Not possible because same indexes will be over-written in single-dimensional array. BTW you can make a multidimensional array of the same keys

Comment: It always amazes me when people ask these questions. How on earth are you supposed to get the names from such an array (if it was possible)? If you `echo $arr['nominal'];` it could output any of the four names. Sounds very unpractical to me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The expected outcome you want is not possible at all, ***because same indexes will be over-written in single-dimensional array.***

Check this to understand what i said above:- https://eval.in/954556

***Now there are 2 closer possiblities of outcomes***, which i am going to mention:-

```
$possibility1 = [];

$possibility2 =[];

foreach($array as $arr){
  $possibility1[] = ['nominal'=>$arr];
  $possibility2['nominal'][] = $arr;

}

print_r($possibility1);//first closer possibility

print_r($possibility2);//second closer possibility
```

Output:- https://eval.in/954559

Comment: Thank you veri much

Answer (score 1):

you can make a multi-dimensional array for this purpose

```
$arr = array('a','b','c','d');


for($i=0;$i<count($arr);$i++){

  $newArr['nominal'][$i] = $arr[$i];

}

print_r($newArr);
```

Comment: Thank u very much :)